# Oracle using correct filter

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I got this SQL-Statement so far:

```
   select * 
    from 
    table1,
    table2
    where table1.fk = table2.ID
    AND table2.id = 4
```

which gives me the following output:

```
[...] [...] Rights                             [...] [...]

 ...   ...  ( ID IN ( 10 , 700000 , 80 , 5 ) )  ...   ...
 ...   ...  ( ID IN ( 500000 , 10 , 80 , 5 ) )  ...   ...
 ...   ...  ( ID IN ( 10 , 5 , 80 , 900000 ) )  ...   ...
```

I need to write in my `where` that it only shows me rows in which the numbers in `Rights` are for example `700000` or below.

In this case only `row` `1` and `2` should be shown.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Add `and rights < 700000` to the query.

Comment: I tried but Rights is a varchar.. thats my problem

Comment: That's a problem, don't have varchar column to store numeric data... Will cast(rights as integer) work?

Comment: to_number(rights) < 700000

Comment: to_number(rights) gives me error: invalid number

Comment: So, rights has non numeric values. How do you want to compare this to a numeric value of 700000?

Comment: also, create table and insert statements would be nice to help you achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you work out what you need to do:

```
with      t1 as (select 1 fk from dual union all
                 select 2 fk from dual union all
                 select 3 fk from dual),
          t2 as (select 1 id, 'ID IN ( 10 , 700000 , 80 , 5 )' rights from dual union all
                 select 2 id, 'ID IN ( 500000 , 10 , 80 , 5 )' rights from dual union all
                 select 3 id, 'ID IN ( 10 , 5 , 80 , 900000 , 203 )' rights from dual),
  pivoted_t2 as (select t2.id,
                        t2.rights,
                        rtrim(ltrim(UPPER(t2.rights), 'ID N('), ' )') rights_stripped,
                        to_number(trim(regexp_substr(rtrim(ltrim(UPPER(t2.rights), 'ID N('), ' )'), '[^,]+', 1, level))) rights_item,
                        max(level) over (partition by t2.id) num_items
                 from   t2
                 connect by prior t2.id = t2.id
                            and prior dbms_random.value is not null
                            and trim(regexp_substr(rtrim(ltrim(UPPER(t2.rights), 'ID N('), ' )'), '[^,]+', 1, level)) is not null)
select t1.fk,
       pt2.rights
from   t1
       inner join pivoted_t2 pt2 on (t1.fk = pt2.id)
where  pt2.rights_item <= 700000
group by t1.fk,
         pt2.rights,
         pt2.num_items
having count(*) = pt2.num_items;

        FK RIGHTS                              
---------- ------------------------------------
         1 ID IN ( 10 , 700000 , 80 , 5 )      
         2 ID IN ( 500000 , 10 , 80 , 5 )
```

Basically, you'll need to split out the rights into their individual items, work out how many items there are in total for each set of rights, and then work out how many are below your specified value. If you get the same number of values returned that are in the set, then you know all the items match your filter.

ETA: I can't guarantee that this will perform well, especially for a large amount of data, but if you're going to insist on storing your data in this manner, you'll have to accept that performance will most likely suffer.